# XSL - How to match consecutive comma-separated tags

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to match a series of xml tags that are comma separated, and to then apply an xslt transformation on the whole group of nodes plus text.  For example, given the following partial XML:

```
<p>Some text here
    <xref id="1">1</xref>,
    <xref id="2">2</xref>,
    <xref id="3">3</xref>.
</p>
```

I would like to end up with:

```
<p>Some text here <sup>1,2,3</sup>.</p>
```

A much messier alternate would also be acceptable at this point:

```
<p>Some text here <sup>1</sup><sup>,</sup><sup>2</sup><sup>,</sup><sup>3</sup>.</p>
```

I have the transformation to go from a single xref to a sup:

```
<xsl:template match="xref"">
    <sup><xsl:apply-templates/></sup>
</xsl:template>
```

But I'm at a loss as to how to match a group of nodes separated by commas.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, not too long and not too-complex XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: Also added detailed explanation.

Comment: I have updated my solution after being alerted by @Flynn1179 that it was producing not exactly the wanted output. Now this solution produces the desired "good format"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. +1.

Here's an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
   version="2.0">
   <xsl:variable name="comma-regex">^\s*,\s*$</xsl:variable>

   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Don't directly process xrefs that are second or later in a comma-separated series.
      Note that this template has a higher default priority than the following one,
      because of the predicate. -->
   <xsl:template match="xref[preceding-sibling::node()[1]/
      self::text()[matches(., $comma-regex)]/
      preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::xref]" />

   <!-- Don't directly process comma text nodes that are in the middle of a series. -->
   <xsl:template match="text()[matches(., $comma-regex) and
      preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::xref and following-sibling::*[1]/self::xref]" />

   <!-- for xrefs that first (or solitary) in a comma-separated series: -->
   <xsl:template match="xref">
      <sup>
         <xsl:call-template name="process-xref-series">
            <xsl:with-param name="next" select="." />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </sup>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="process-xref-series">
      <xsl:param name="next"/>
      <xsl:if test="$next">
         <xsl:value-of select="$next"/>
         <xsl:variable name="followingXref"
            select="$next/following-sibling::node()[1]/
                     self::text()[matches(., $comma-regex)]/
                     following-sibling::*[1]/self::xref"/>
         <xsl:if test="$followingXref">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="process-xref-series">
               <xsl:with-param name="next" select="$followingXref"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:if>         
      </xsl:if>

   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(This could be simplified if we could make some assumptions about the input.)

Run against the sample input you gave, the result is:

```
<p>Some text here
   <sup>1,2,3</sup>.
</p>
```

Comment: BTW the only reason this requires XSLT 2.0 is the regex match function. If you change `matches(., $comma-regex)` to `normalize-space(.) = ','`, as in @Martin's answer, you could use XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Note - I needed to add priority="1" into the xsl:template that matched the xrefs that occurred after the first xref.  I was getting ambiguous match warnings, and the additional xrefs were passing through the process-xref-series.  This worked well - thanks!

Comment: Also in that same template, changing `preceding-sibling::node()/` to `preceding-sibling::node()[1]/` allows for multiple xref spans within a single `p`

Comment: @Pocket: thanks for the correction about `preceding-sibling::node()[1]` - it's what I should have written in the first place. Editing my answer now. Actually I had to add `[1]` in two other places (in the template that matched `text()`) as well.

Comment: @Pocket: What XSLT processor was giving you ambiguous match warnings? The template you mentioned should have a default priority of 0.5, because the match has a predicate. The template with `match="xref"` should have a default priority of 0 (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-default-priority).

Comment: I'm using Oxygen XML Editor, and the processor I'm using is Saxon-HE 9.3.0.4.  The ambiguity could have come from some other parts of the doc, I suppose.  My situation is more complex than the example I originally provided - there are actually multiple `xref` tags that have different `ref-type` attributes.  The `xref` that gets converted into superscript has `ref-type="bibr"`. So, it's definitely possible I messed something up in adapting your solution.  Even so, it can't hurt to explicitly set the priority. Thanks again.

Comment: Pocket: You're right, templates with explicit priority are more readable and probably more maintainable... even though it's tempting to take advantage of "elegant" default priorities when they work out advantageously.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Thanks to @Flynn1179 who alerted me that the solution wasn't producing exactly the wanted output, I have slightly modified it. **Now the wanted "good" format is produced**.

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match=
     "xref[not(preceding-sibling::node()[1]
                  [self::text() and starts-with(.,',')]
               )
          ]">

      <xsl:variable name="vBreakText" select=
      "following-sibling::text()[not(starts-with(.,','))][1]"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vPrecedingTheBreak" select=
       "$vBreakText/preceding-sibling::node()"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vFollowing" select=
      ".|following-sibling::node()"/>

      <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select=
      "$vFollowing[count(.|$vPrecedingTheBreak)
                  =
                   count($vPrecedingTheBreak)
                  ]
      "/>

      <sup>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="$vGroup" mode="group"/>
      </sup>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$vBreakText"/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="text()" mode="group">
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one, but made more complex and interesting):

```
<p>Some text here    
    <xref id="1">1</xref>,    
    <xref id="2">2</xref>,    
    <xref id="3">3</xref>.
    <ttt/>
    <xref id="4">4</xref>,
    <xref id="5">5</xref>,
    <xref id="6">6</xref>.
    <zzz/>
</p>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>Some text here        
    <sup>1,2,3</sup>.    
    <ttt/>
    <sup>4,5,6</sup>.    
    <zzz/>
</p>
```

**Explanation**:

1. We use a "fined-grained" identity rule, which processes the document node-by node in document order and copies the matched node "as-is"
2. We override the identity rule with a template that matches any `xref` element that is the first in a group of `xref` elements, each of which (but the last one) is followed by an immediate text-node-sibling that starts with the ',' character. Here we find the first text-node-sibling that breaks the rule (its starting character isn't ','.
3. Then we find all the nodes in the group, using the Kayessian (after @Michael Kay) formula for the intersection of two nodesets. This formula is: `$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]`
4. Then we process all nodes in the group in a mode named "group".
5. Finally, we apply templates (in anonymous mode) to the breaking text node (that is the first node following the group), so that the chain of processing continues.

Comment: The result given is not the wanted result; the commas are supposed to be enclosed in `sup` tags. I suggest adding this template: `<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()=',']" mode="group"><sup>,</sup></xsl:template>`.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Thank you -- I hadn't noticed that. Now I have updated the solution to produce the "good" format. :)

Comment: Interesting identity rule. +1

Comment: Hm, when given the input `<p>Some text <xref>1</xref>, <xref>2</xref>,<em>and more.</em></p>`, it outputs `<p>Some text <sup>1,2,and more.</sup></p>`. "and more" shouldn't be inside `<sup>` should it? Also, the input `<p>Some text <xref id="1">1</xref>, <em>and more.</em></p>` gives `<p>Some text <sup/></p>`: the 1 disappeared.

Comment: @LarsH: I didn't have time to test this extensively, thanks for the good catch.

Answer (score 2):

The second alternative can be achieved with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/text()[normalize-space() = ',' and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::xref]]">
  <sup>,</sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref">
  <sup>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </sup>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an almost trivial solution to your 'messy alternative':

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="xref">
  <sup>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)=',']">
  <sup>,</sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: I just noticed it's almost a clone of Martin's solution, except without the additional check of a preceding xref element on the commas. His is probably safer :)

And a slightly less trivial solution to your preferred result, although this only works if you only have one collection of `xref` tags in any `p` tag. You didn't mention the possibility of more than one collection, and even if there are, I would have thought it unlikely they'd be within the same containing `p` tag. If that can happen though, it's possible to extend it further to allow for that, although it will get a lot more complicated.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="xref[not(preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space(.)=','])]">
  <sup>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::text() | following-sibling::xref">
      <xsl:if test="following-sibling::text()[substring(.,1,1)='.']">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref | text()[normalize-space(.)=',']" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you can use XSLT 2.0 (e.g. with Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XQSharp) then here is an XSLT 2.0 solution that should produce the first output you asked for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::xref or self::text()[normalize-space() = ',']">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
        <sup>
          <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/normalize-space()" separator=""/>
        </sup>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Interesting... you can use a boolean as a grouping key?! I think that makes sense once you wrap your mind around it...

Comment: While very elegant, the drawback with this approach is that if a comma-only text node appears next to an `xref` but not between two `xref`s, it will nevertheless be treated as part of the `<sup>`. E.g. `<p>Some text <xref>1</xref>, <em>and some more.</em></p>`: the comma will come out as part of the `<sup>`, but shouldn't be.